# Iterate through subnet and run portscan function

Tags: python, networking

I'm trying to write a python program that will ping sweep a given network (192.168.0.0/24) for example. And then store the alive hosts in an array. From that array, I want to port scan them using a function I wrote. However, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a condensed version of the script not using the alive hosts, just the entire subnet (its the same idea):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import ipaddress

def portscan(host):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
    try:
        for port in range(75,85):  

            result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))
            if result == 0: #the error indictator returns 0 if the operation succeeds.
                print "port ",port," is open on ", host
            # else:
            #     print "port ",port," is closed"     
            sock.close()
            logging.debug(i)
    except:
        print "no connection on port",port, "from host",host        


def main():
    subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(u'192.168.0.0/29')
    for i in subnet:
        print i
        portscan(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The above just returns:

```
192.168.0.0
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
no connection on port 75 from host 192.168.0.7
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

I've also wrote a script that runs a portscan on one specific host, and it works totally fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys

server = '192.168.0.1'
def portscanner():
    try:
        for port in range(1,445):  
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((server, port))
            if result == 0: #the error indictator returns 0 if the operation succeeds.
                print "port",port," is open on",server
            # else:
            #     print "port ",port," is closed"     
            sock.close()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print " CTRL+C Interruption. Exiting..." 
        sys.exit() 

portscanner()
```

the hard coded ip returns:

```
port 80  is open on 192.168.0.1
port 443  is open on 192.168.0.1
[Finished in 20.3s]
```

I've wrote so many different variations off this to get it to work. But I'm consistently getting it wrong!
I'm also very new to Python, so be gentle!

TL;DR:
iterate through a bunch of IP addresses and call a portscan function on each IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    for port in range(75,85):
```

Your `for` loop is inside the `try` block -- as soon as **one** of the connection attempts fails, it jumps directly to the `except` clause and skips all of the other ports in the loop. Since most systems won't have port 75 open, this will make the "scan" fail.

Move the `for` loop outside the `try`, like you have it in your other script.

Comment: ahhhh that makes sense. However, that produces the follow issue:
`ile "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, IPv4Address found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]`

but if i comment out the portscan(i), the format of the ip address is fine.